# how can I filter only rows that change in one column but the same in the next two columns?

Tags: mysql

I want to have all the for when field and code are repetitive and the ID changes. 
Field should have a value of "position"

```
MyTable
ID     field        code
9990    position    2434
3275    position    2434
3604    position    2434
2436    position    2434
6547    stage       wip
6547    position    5247
3604    type        CAR

Outcome:
ID     field        code
9990    position    2434
3275    position    2434
3604    position    2434
2436    position    2434
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering to the rows, unless another column specifies the ordering.  Do you have such a column?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to query all the rows with field and code has more than one ID.(I'll assume that ID is an autoincrement field).

The next query retrieve all the rows where fields and code has more than one tuple

```
SELECT field,code,COUNT(field) AS `number_of_distinct_IDs`
  FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY field,code
 HAVING COUNT(field)>1;
```

With the result of the previous query you could filter your table, to do that (there's many ways to do it) you could create a temporal table to storage these values, or could use a derived table, it dependents of your requirements and the volume of your data. I'll choose the second one.

The query look like the follow:

```
SELECT ID,pivot.field,pivot.code 
  FROM MyTable AS pivot
  JOIN 
  (
      SELECT field,code
         FROM MyTable
       GROUP BY field,code
         HAVING COUNT(field)>1
  ) AS Filter USING(field,code);
```

I'll Expect this answer could help you

Regards